# Read Cell properties in Visio using vb

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to create a VB macro in Visio that can read the data and properties of the shape. So say I have a Rectangle Shpae in Visio with Cells Name, Description, Type, Size.... and so on.

When I try to read the cells and their values I am only getting the first cell and its value. 
Here is my code . I would appreciate some help here.

```
    Sub Testing()

    Dim excelObj As Object
    Dim excelFile As String
    Dim sheetName As String
   ' Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook

   ' Set excelFile = "C:\Users\hbhasin\Documents\test.xls"
    'Set sheetName = "New Sheet name"

    Set excelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelObj.Workbooks.Add

    Dim pagObj As Visio.Page
    Dim shpsObj As Visio.shapes
    Dim shapes As Visio.shapes
    Dim shpObj As Visio.Shape
    Dim CellObj As Visio.Cell


    Dim Storage() As String
    Dim iShapeCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer



    Set pagObj = ActivePage
    Set shpsObj = pagObj.shapes
    iShapeCount = shpsObj.Count
    Debug.Print iShapeCount



   ReDim Storage(8, iShapeCount - 1)

    For i = 1 To iShapeCount - 1
        Set shpObj = shpsObj(i)
        Storage(1, i - 1) = shpObj.Name
        If shpObj.CellExists("Prop.Name", visExistsLocally) Then
            Set CellObj = shpObj.CellsU("Prop.Name")
            Storage(2, i - 1) = CellObj.ResultStr("")
        End If
        If shpObj.CellExists("Prop.Description", visExistsLocally) Then
            Debug.Print "Test the IF statement"
            Set CellObj = shpObj.CellsU("Prop.Description")
            Storage(3, i - 1) = CellObj.ResultStr("")
        End If


    Next


    For i = 0 To iShapeCount - 1
        Debug.Print "Name- " & Storage(0, i)
        Debug.Print "Description-" & Storage(1, i)



    Next







  End Sub
```

In fact, I have put a debug statement within the second if clause and that does not execute which tells me the compiler is not even seeing the second cell or any cell after.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting the Description Shape Data it maybe that it's not local, but inherited from its master.  Here's a slight modification of your code (with the Excel part removed as I don't think it's relevant here):

```
Sub Testing()

Dim shpsObj As Visio.shapes
Set shpsObj = ActivePage.shapes

Dim iShapeCount As Integer
iShapeCount = shpsObj.Count

'Assumes you want an array of shape data
Dim Storage() As String
ReDim Storage(iShapeCount - 1, 2)

'Visio shapes are 1 based so use full count
Dim i As Integer
Dim shpObj As Visio.Shape
For i = 1 To iShapeCount
    Set shpObj = shpsObj(i)

    Storage(i - 1, 0) = shpObj.Name 'Do you want NameU?

    'Assumes you don't care whether the cell is local or inherited
    If shpObj.CellExistsU("Prop.Name", visExistsAnywhere) Then
        Storage(i - 1, 1) = shpObj.CellsU("Prop.Name").ResultStr("")
    End If

    If shpObj.CellExistsU("Prop.Description", visExistsAnywhere) Then
        Storage(i - 1, 2) = shpObj.CellsU("Prop.Description").ResultStr("")
    End If
Next

Dim j As Long
For j = LBound(Storage, 1) To UBound(Storage, 1)
    Debug.Print "Shape Name- " & Storage(j, 0)
    Debug.Print "  Prop.Name- " & Storage(j, 1)
    Debug.Print "  Prop.Description- " & Storage(j, 2)
Next j

End Sub
```

If you're just running through all the shapes on the page, then you might want to look at For Each shp In shapes as an alternative.  Check out this page for more details:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/11/looping-through.html

Also, you might want to try look at the [CreateSelection page method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767064%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to narrow down your target shapes if you're dealing with a large number